# Need SED or AWK script to do strlen optimization

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I just need a little help cause I rarely touch sed or awk.  I'm trying to replace

```
String1.append("Hello");   // regexp to find this is: \w*\.append\(".*"\)
```

with

```
String1.append("Hello", 5);  // note it has to figure out the length of "Hello"
```

And I need to do this search and replace across hundreds of thousands of files.  And "Hello could be anything... including "\n\n\n" which should be 3 not 6.  Example:

```
s.append("\n\n\n");  ---> s.append("\n\n\n", 3);
```

Thanks in advance for any help...  I'm thinking I need awk to do this so I'm reading a tutorial about the basics of awk right now...

Comment: The target language is Java, right?  If it were C you could look at [Coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) maybe. Perhaps something similar exists for Java.

Comment: So what happens with `s.append(foo)`, or does that never happen?

Comment: Target language is C++.  It's a bunch of .cpp files I am trying to add this optimization to.  @Idav1s: do you mean foo is a variable?  That's why my regular expression looks for static strings with quotes.

Comment: Just took at a look at Coccinelle, it's overkill for what I'm trying to do.  I want a simple command line script that uses regex.  (I mean I could do this in C++ but it's really not the best tool for this job.)

Comment: It's trivial except for counting "\n" as a newline since what "\n" means is context-dependent. If printed as just "\n" it's a newline but as part of "\\n" it's a backslash followed by the letter "n".

Comment: Not sure if I follow you Ed.  If interpreting C strings with escape characters lengths properly is a problem, I could preprocess and remove the backslashes for the purposes of calculating the length - assuming no \X is used (Don't think it is.)

Comment: An example: how long are the strings "\n" and "\\n"? The first you apparently want to be length "1" instead of "2" as you consider "\n" as one newline character instead of 2 characters (a backslash and an n). The second example you probably want to be length 2 instead of "3" as "\\n" is an escaped backslash (which is just a backslash for printing) followed by the letter "n". Now, what about "\\\n"? So you can't just see "\n" and assume it's a newline character as it all depends what sequence of characters precede it. Actually - maybe just stripping odd numbers of backslashes would work.

Comment: @mrjustinmooser - by the way, what awk tutorial are you reading? Most of the ones online are absolute nonsense (or at least contain many incorrect examples) so beware! To learn awk get the book  Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins. Do not buy the sed&awk book or any other book, just that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to run this on some files containing code, here's an example of that full functionality:

```
$ cat file
foo() {
   String1.append("Hello");
   if (bar) {
      s.append("\n\n\n");
   }
   else {
      s.append("\n\\n\n\\\n");
   }
}
$
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/[[:alnum:]_]+\.append\(".*"\)/) {
    split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH), orig, /"/)

    head = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) orig[1]
    tail = orig[3] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)

    tgt = orig[2]
    gsub(/[\\][\\]/,"X",tgt)
    gsub(/[\\]/,"",tgt)

    $0 = sprintf("%s\"%s\", %d%s", head, orig[2], length(tgt), tail)
}
{ print }
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
foo() {
   String1.append("Hello", 5);
   if (bar) {
      s.append("\n\n\n", 3);
   }
   else {
      s.append("\n\\n\n\\\n", 6);
   }
}
```

I replaced the "\w" from the example in the original posted question with the POSIX equivalent "[[:alnum:]_]" for portability. "\w" will work with GNU awk and some other tools, but not all tools and not all awks.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble with this script because it seems to change a lot of whitespace in the file (not just the line it is appending).  Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is C++, have you considered using the preprocessor? Also, instead of computing the length of each string yourself, you could consider using the `sizeof` operator.

```
#define append(x) appendSize(x, sizeof(x))
```

Of course, this assumes that the "x" passed to `append` is always a string literal (but, then, if it weren't then no find and replace script is going to work either).

Comment: +1 for the use of sizeof(), IF this is C++ (from the posted code it could be other languages too). I'd probably still do the search/replace though rather than introduce a macro just for the sake of code clarity. Actually, if this is C++ couldn't you just modify the method in it's definition so that append(foo) calls append(foo, strlen(foo))?

Comment: @Dan: What do you mean "no find and replace script is going to work either?"  That is exactly what this question is asking, and with the use of regex it is simple to find only string literals and apply the optimization.

Comment: @Ed: of course... std::string already has a standard append(const string&) method.  This is an optimization specifically to AVOID strlen when possible!  :)

Comment: @mrjustinmooser I meant that find-and-replace scripts will only work if the argument to `append` is always a string literal, as opposed to a variable. For instance, how can you make a sed, awk, or perl script figure out the string length for this line of code `String1.append(foo)`? It can't be done because the length of `foo` isn't known at compile time. If you do choose to use a find-and-replace script, I'd still suggest using `sizeof` instead of having the script compute the string length. It's less error-prone (it won't get tripped up by escaped characters in the string).

Comment: @EdMorton I'm not sure that `append("foo")` is less clear than `append("foo", 3)` or `append("foo", sizeof("foo") - 1)`. Especially if `append` gets used a lot, which it sounds like it does.

Comment: @DanMoulding macros can be useful but often obfuscate code. It's hard enough to figure out where things are defined in C++ (my class? a parent class? a friend class? a structure def? a template? a macro? etc.) so any time you can make the code explicit without sacrificing maintainability is a good thing.

Comment: @EdMorton I give 'em one month of maintenance tops before someone changes one of the strings and forgets to also change the size argument :)  But I'll agree with you that it's difficult to navigate C++ code and macros aren't helpful in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

This might be better suited as a comment, but it is harder to show the information.  It seems to me that trying to optimize string length through modifying the source is maybe not the best solution.  Maybe there is a good reason for it, but leaving it to the compiler might be a better solution (and much simpler).  Depending on the compiler and the options, the strlen() call may not even be used.  The compiler can figure out lengths of constant strings.  For example, consider this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   string s = argv[1];
   cout << s << endl;
   s.append( " stuff" );
   cout << s << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

When compiled with -O (`g++ -O file.c`), the pertinent bit of assembly is:

```
400ad2:       ba 06 00 00 00          mov    $0x6,%edx
400ad7:       be 6c 0c 40 00          mov    $0x400c6c,%esi
400adc:       48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
400adf:       e8 0c fe ff ff          callq  4008f0 <_ZNSs6appendEPKcm@plt>
```

Notice the first `mov` instruction.  It has the length 6 already figured out.

Using `-O2` with a Microsoft compiler (v16.00.40219.01) produces something similar:

```
0000005C: 6A 06              push        6
0000005E: 68 00 00 00 00     push        offset ??_C@_06PNGALGA@?5stuff?$AA@
00000063: 8D 4C 24 0C        lea         ecx,[esp+0Ch]
00000067: E8 00 00 00 00     call        ?append@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAAV12@PBDI@Z
```

Comment: Hi Mark, although the compiler certainly knows it is length 6, how can it be smart enough to call the correct "append" method (the one that doesn't call strlen?)  Are you assuming I'm using std::string?  Unfortunately I'm stuck with a 3rd party string that implements the std::string interface (as far as append methods anyways)

Comment: Even with a 3rd party library, you could probably use strlen() in the calls.  Many (most?) modern compilers will replace a hardcoded `strlen( "abcde" )` with the constant `5`.

Comment: Are you sure?  I know String.Append("Foo", strlen("Foo")) will do exactly what you are talking about...  But it sounds like you are saying that String.Append("Foo") although it internally calls strlen() the compiler is smart enough to replace it with 3?  I doubt it.

Comment: No - if the string is passed to another method then the compiler would not be able to do that optimization. If it is a macro in place then it could.

Answer (score -1):

Someone please improve on this solution:

```
x='String1.append("Hello");'
len=`echo $x | sed 's/\\//g' | sed 's/\w*\.append("\(.*\)");/\1/' | awk '{print length($0)}'`
echo $x | sed "s/\(\w*\.append(\".*\"\)\(.*\)/\1,$len\2/"
```

This seems to solve the original problem but in multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks, this is getting me on the right track.  I was originally struggling with getting the input string into awk so I could do a length() on it.

Comment: There's a problem though... echo $x | sed 's/\w*\.append("\(.*\)");/\1/' returns "shello" and as a result length($0) returns 6 instead of 5.

Comment: Trying to figure out more about the "/\1/" stuff.   I have no idea what to search for in google to figure out if there is a way to grab the part between quotes.

Comment: Backreferences, cool!  So I tried doing something like this: echo $x | sed 's/\w*\.append("\((.*)\)");/\1/' (note the extra parenthesis around .* to create a back reference.  Then I try to reference the backreference with \1.  But this doesn't work.  Just outputs the entire match, not the part between quotes.

Comment: I had tested it on bash and it worked.  May be you should try to run the pipe components separately to localize the problem.

Comment: sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line. For anything else, just use awk.

Comment: \1 is what is "remembered" by using \(...\) in the original pattern.  Notice the use of \(.*\) after append; that gives you the string to find the length of.

Comment: @unxnut - could you modify your answer to show how it would work on the sample input file I posted in my answer in this thread just so we can see what the full sed solution looks like for comparison?

Answer (score -1):

Yay for perl!

```
x='String1.append("Hello");'
echo $x | perl -pe 's/(\w*\.append\(\")(.*)(\"\);)/my($len)=length($2); $_="$1$2, ${len}$3";/e'
```

Comment: It doesn't produce the expected output for the "\n\n\n" sample input or for the other case I added to my answer.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/(\w*\.append\(\")(.*)(\")(\);)/my($len)=length(eval("qq{$2}")); $_="$1$2$3, ${len}$4";/e'`

Comment: @BradGilbert awww, my perl fu is weak it seems.